# How to randomly select five data points on moon dataset

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, k-means

```
X,y = make_moons(n_samples=200,noise=0, random_state=0)
n_clusters=5
KMeans(n_clusters = 15,random_state=10)
model.fit(X)
centroids = model.cluster_centers_
labels = model.labels_
```

How to randomly select five data points from moons dataset for testify whether they are outlier or not?

Comment: Are you asking how to generate 5 random indices for dataset with 200 records? `from random import sample; sample(range(200), 5)`